# android application in fixed size window

Tags: android

is it possible to run an android application in a fixed size window?

for example , i want to run my application in a fixed size window and at the same time i should be able to control the remaining area of the device screen(read messages, play music, ect..).

Comment: update your question with more detail so that other can understand about the tasks that you want to implement exactly.

Answer (score 4):

I think..

you can use following in all your activity to show at specific **gravity**(left/right/top/bottom) and **Layout**(hight/width) of the activity in OnCreate() method.

```
    getWindow().setGravity(gravity); 
    getWindow().setLayout(width, height); 
    getWindow().setAttributes(a);
```

More you can here in **[DeveloperSite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)**

This is how I used ,
         android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes();

```
     WMLP.height =100;    
     WMLP.width = 100;                
     getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);  
     getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: thank you Frankenstein,my application is resized and shifted at the bottom but the remaining area will not be usable. it is physically occupying all the screen. for example if the screen size is  320*480, my application will run within the bottom 100*100. the remaining area will be black

Comment: already tried, all you can do is have a look of what is behind, but you cant take action. i think there is no way to take control of two windows at the same time, a running application will physically occupy all the screen. thanks

Comment: AFAIK yes that's true "You Can't Get Control Over Two Screen At A Time"...cause both are different activity..and you can't have control on two activity at a time..

Comment: I think you need to head in the direction of an ActivityGroup.

Comment: @jsmith is it for me?..you mean to say can get control over 2 screen using ActivityGroup..Sorry..but i have no experience of using ActivityGroup..so asking you..